# Scala package object vs Predef

Tags: scala, predef

What's the difference between something being defined in the `scala` package object and in `Predef`?

Is `Predef` just a relic from pre-2.8 when package objects didn't exist, or is there some other reason why we need both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the ScalaDoc,

> "The `Predef` object provides definitions that are accessible in all
>   Scala compilation units without explicit qualification"

So, it is not a package object itself, but acts as one in terms of providing functionality to "all Scala compilation units"

As for why the situation exists, I think you are right, looks to be a [legacy issue](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects_2.html)

As for why it persists, there may continue to be [limitations of package objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects_3.html) that prevent PreDef from being merged.

Comment: I wonder if there are any concrete examples of things in Predef that couldn't go in the scala package object

Comment: Predef may very well work as a package object, but there must be a reason why Scala core devs have chosen to keep Predef as a non-package object if that is the case. A clue in Predef is: "scala.`package` // to force scala package object to be seen". There must be an "import Predef._" provided by the compiler that gives us functionality we would otherwise not get were Predef a package object. Anyway, I bet the scala-lang user group would be able to shed some light on the issue...